# Polymorphic Associations with doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, polymorphic-associations

I need to store `reference object` as a field of my entity & the `reference object` can be an instance of multiple different entities.
I thought about polymorphic associations but it seems doctrine only support it as `Inheritance Mapping`.
Is there any way to associate a field with different target entities and with out make all of my target entities a child of an another one?

---

**Edit:**
actually I have an `assignmentBundle` & user can be refered for an assignment from other entities in application (`Invoice`, `PriceCheck`, `Warranty` & etc.) and I need to show from which entity each assignment is created.
my assignment looks like this:

```
namespace ITW\AssignmentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ITW\IndicatorBundle\Entity\Letter;

/**
 * Assignment
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ITW\AssignmentBundle\Entity\AssignmentRepository")
 */
class Assignment
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="explanation", type="text")
     */
    private $explanation;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ITW\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="uid", referencedColumnName="id",nullable= FALSE)
     */
    private $user;


    /**
     *  ** This Should be the entity that the assignment is created from **
     */
    private $sourceEntity;
```

I need to fill `sourceEntity` with the object id that creates the assignment for user

Comment: To better explain your question could you post a visual model as example?

Comment: @gp_sflover: please check my edit on question

Comment: You can add `sourceClass` and `sourceId` fields to the entity. You will have to do some extra work to resolve these 2 fields to actual objects.

Comment: @broncha: So it's not possible to make Doctrine to manage this relationship automatically and i need to read them by myself?

Comment: @4r1y4n Not that I know of. Sylius has a component that does something similar. But I am not completely sure, if that can help. Check https://github.com/Sylius/Originator. There is no documentation about the component. You would need to implement `OriginAwareInterface` in your `Assignment` entity. Check https://github.com/Sylius/Originator/blob/master/Originator/Originator.php for accessing and setting originator